# JavaScript function logic to play/pause HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a script which plays/pauses a HTML5 video based on the window size. When the user enters fullscreen, the video plays. When the user exits fullscreen, the video pauses, as expected. If you enter fullscreen again on the paused video, it will call a play and then pause immediately.

Here's the play/pause script and the console logs:

```
// Listen for exiting fullscreen, hide video element.
    $("#" + m).on("webkitfullscreenchange", function(e) {
      this.className = "hide";
      if($("#" + m).get(0).paused) {
        v.play();
        console.log('playing...')
      } else {
        v.pause();
        console.log('pausing...')
      }
```

[image: console]

Here's a **[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/Bjqeob?editors=1010)** with representative HTML and the full script.

What can I do in my logic to prevent the second pause call being made?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem, I may be missing some context. Could you show us more of your code, particularly how `m` and `v` are defined, where you set up the handler that requests full screen and if relevant bits of your HTML ?

Comment: @Arthur Just added a link to a CodePen with a representative chunk & the full script.

Comment: You are reacting to a _change_ in the fullscreen status only, but you’re not actually checking whether the event was triggered by going _in_ or _out_ of fullscreen. http://www.intheloftstudios.com/blog/detecting-html5-video-fullscreen-and-events has an easy example how to determine that.

Comment: @Cbroe That did it - thanks for the link to the article. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Great! Why not make that into a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), with what your code now looks like? Always good for some rep ;-)

Comment: @CBroe had part of the solution, but your full code has another problem, related to the way you set up your handlers (cf my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of your problem.

Here is the general structure of your code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.cell').on('click', function() {

    // some more code ...

    $("#" + m).on("webkitfullscreenchange", function(e) {
      // here the code for the event handler that pauses and plays the video
    });
  )};
)};
```

You can see that the code that adds the handler on the "webkitfullscreenchange" event... is inside the handler for the .cell click event !

Here what happens : **every time you click on the cell**, you request the fullscreen, and **you add a new event handler** on the "webkitfullscreenchange" event (in jQuery, `on` register a new event handler, it does not replace the previous one if there was one).

The first time you click, you add the handler and you request full screen mode : it emits the event, your single handler gets it and plays the video.

But the second time you click, you request full screen mode and you add a second handler. When the event is emitted, **both handlers react** : the first one plays the video, and the second... immediately pauses it.

So here's part of the solution : just remove the part where you register more event handlers out of the click event handler (as a rule of thumb, situations when you have to set up handlers inside other handlers are very specific, so do not do it if you don't have any specific reason).

Why part ? Because even if it solves your first problem, it does leave another one: what happens if you click, let the video finish, and then quit full screen mode? The handler will get called, verify if the video is playing, notice that it is not and start playing it... even if you just left full screen.

So here's the final solution: set up your handler so that it checks if you just went in or out of full screen mode(using `document.webkitIsFullScreen`), and play or pause accordingly, as per @CBroe suggestion in the comments.

```
$('video').on('webkitfullscreenchange', function(e) {
  if(document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
    this.play();
  } else {
    this.className = "hide";
    this.pause();
  }
});
```

I [forked your CodePen and set up the full solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEzZxd?editors=1010) if you want to have a look.